# unable to see any value from mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am using the procedure below : 
But I am not getting any value when I type this in localhost phpmyadmin/mysql:

```
call GetAllProducts() ;
```

it returns no value as select statement does?
where can I execute to see the values?
How do I make it wotk.I really appreciate any help.
Thanks in Advance.

The procedure below is successfully executed and stored .I checked that.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM products;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You get no errors? Are you connected to the right database via PMA (not a test db, for example)? What you have should exactly work. Please clarify also, can you execute it via `call GetAllProducts()` from the MySQL command line? That you have used `DELIMITER` (which is a MySQL CLI-specific command) implies that you have access to the command-line client `mysql`...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable of handling multi queries. The execution of some stored routines may fail! Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any problems.`  --------- I get the following response when I click execute  in routines in  mysql.

Comment: @jason I think you've just answered your own question... go into PMAs `config.inc.php` file and change the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']` to **mysqli** (and ensure you're using MySQLi, or better yet PDO as that copes better with procedures I've found, in your application).

Comment: @jason That seems inconsistent though.  Have you already successfully created the procedure, or are you trying to create it with PMA?  If you were merely executing an already created SP, that only counts as one query as far as PHP is concerned.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it's only one query but returns multiple records and that, IIRC, is what the old `mysql_` extension couldn't cope with... I could be wrong though (it's been a while). It couldn't really deal with procedures that were more complex than stored functions.

Comment: @CD001 Hmm, I guess I never executed SP's via `mysql_*()` in PHP.  That procedure does only return one result set, be it multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of times you mention using phpMyAdmin; what version do you have?

I'm unable to reproduce your problem; it works properly for me. From the database, click the `Routines` tab, then for your GetAllProducts routine click the Execute link.

[image]

Comment: I tried the same and `You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable of handling multi queries. The execution of some stored routines may fail! Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any problems.` --------- I get the following response when I click execute in routines in mysql.  using latest phpmyadmin/MAMP

Comment: Sorry, based on the comments above I thought you already switched to mysqli. I suggest editing your config.inc.php and adding the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';` as suggested by CD001.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you for additional queries.Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm what phpMyAdmin version are you using? It's displayed on the main page toward the bottom right. I just tested with the mysql extension and did not get that message at all. My test procedure is simply ``SELECT * from `testtable` `` and returns 4 rows with 12 columns.

Comment: Server version: 5.5.33